# Enforce xlim and xbound even when a textbox is outside the range

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pyplot is expanding my figure in order to show text that appears outside of xlim() and xbound(). I don't want the figure expanded, I would just like to show the parts of the figure in the xlimits.

In the example, I set the x limits to 30, but pyplot stretches the display to show the 'bar' text. I want to know how to restrict the entire image to the [0, 30] range:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(10, 10, 'foo')
ax.text(50, 10, 'bar')
ax.set_xlim([0, 30], auto=False)
ax.set_xbound([0, 30])
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: the broken figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can pass `clip_on=True` to `text`, so that the text is "clipped" if it is outside the bounds of the axes

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots()
t1 = ax.text(10, 10, 'foo', clip_on=True)
t2 = ax.text(50, 10, 'bar', clip_on=True)
ax.set_xlim([0, 30], auto=False)
ax.set_ylim([0, 30], auto=False)
f.tight_layout()
```

or

- you can use `Artist.set_in_layout(False)` so that specific artists (in this case the `Text` object) to not be considered when calculating the `tight_layout`

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots()
t1 = ax.text(10, 10, 'foo')
t2 = ax.text(50, 10, 'bar')
t1.set_in_layout(False)
t2.set_in_layout(False)
ax.set_xlim([0, 30], auto=False)
ax.set_ylim([0, 30], auto=False)
f.tight_layout()
```

or

- you can *not* use `tight_layout()` so that matplotlib does not resize your axes (and then the text that's outside the bounds will not be displayed)